# How Does Type Casting in Java Actually Work?

Tags: java, object, casting

Suppose `A` is a superclass of `B` and each have property `i` with default value is `0`.

```
B b = new B();
System.out.print(b.i);
A a = b;
a.i = 3;
System.out.print(b.i);
```

Why the output is `00` not `03`?

Does casting create new object?

Edit :

These are A and B :

```
class A {
    int i;
}
class B extends A {
    int i;
}
```

Comment: Because if each one has a "property", a field, then those are separate fields and hold different values.  Fields can be re-declared, unlike methods.

Comment: No. It tells the compiler another type for the *reference.* But as `a.i` and `b.i` are different, assigning to one doesn't affect the other.

Comment: With your edit, Elliot's answer is clearly correct for your question.  `B.i` and `A.i` are two separate fields, they get set to different values by your code example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing `A` or `B` it's somewhat hard to speculate, but it sounds like you have a second field `i` in `B` that **shadows** the field `i` in `A`. Here is a complete self contained example,

```
static class A {
    public int i = 0;
}

static class B extends A {
    public B() {
        this.i = 2;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    B b = new B();
    System.out.println(b.i);
    A a = b;
    a.i = 3;
    System.out.println(b.i);
}
```

And that outputs

```
2
3
```

Clearly demonstrating that casting does **not** create a new object.